# Multiple processes wsmprovhost.exe do not terminate after closing remote PowerShell sessions

Tags: c#, session, powershell, powershell-remoting, wsman

I am connecting to remote computers from C# application using PowerShell Remoting (directly from C# code). That works fine, however every such connection leaves a new instance of process **wsmprovhost.exe** (WSMan host process) lingering on the target computer. They never exit and consume small amounts (<0.1%) of CPU time.

Here's sample code which I use to open PowerShell sessions:

```
 WSManConnectionInfo ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(
       false, host, 5985, 
       "/wsman", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", 
       credential
 );
 ci.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Credssp;
 runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
 runspace.ApartmentState = Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();
 runspace.Open();
```

... and here's how currently I close that session:

```
 runspace.Disconnect();
 runspace.Close();
 runspace.Dispose();
```

I ruled out possibility that anything that we do in this runspace causes this, because **wsmprovhost.exe** stays there even we don't do anything with it - i.e. simply connect and then disconnect.

The problem does **not** happen when I do equivalent action manually from PS command line - i.e:

```
Enter-PSSession $host -Credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP
...
Exit-PSSession
```

In the latter case, an instance of **wsmprovhost.exe** appears after *Enter-PSSession*, and then closes immediately after *Exit-PSSession*.

I tried the following things so far, none of which helped:

- Using `RunspacePool` instead of `Runspace`
- All combinations and permutations of `Disconnect`/`Close`/`Dispose`
- Setting `CancelTimeout` on `WSManConnectionInfo` to small values (1ms)

Am I missing something simple ? 
What is the correct way of closing programmatically opened PowerShell sessions ?

---

Edit: Windows 7, PowerShell 3.0 and .Net 4.0 on all systems.

Edit 2:
I found that setting `IdleTimeout` on `WSManConnectionInfo` to 60000 (60 seconds - lowest allowed value) makes **wsmprovhost.exe** exit one minute after disconnection. However, in command-line scenario, IdleTimeout is 2 hours, and yet wsmprovhost.exe terminates immediately after disconnect. Also, I now noticed that wsmprovhost.exe started in response to C# actions does exit after all, but only in 2 hours. 
One minute is certainly better than 2 hours, but in heavy-load scenarios, our application may have to run PowerShell frequently enough for 1-minute closure time to be a problem.

Comment: What are the source and target operating systems? What version of PowerShell on each?

Comment: Windows 7, PowerShell 3.0 and .Net 4.0 on all systems

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger call Flush() on which object ? Output stream ? Something else ? There are no streams or anything else besides Runspace in open-and-close scenario